# Remove the focus on GridView images

Tags: android, image, gridview

I am displaying list of images using the GridView.

I want to remove the focus(highlighted by a color) on the images when I scroll the GridView
Is there any API available on GridView to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add android:listSelector="#00000000" for GridView

Give it a try